Correctly using scale_fill_gradientn() and scale_color_gradientn()
I want to correctly set up scale_*_gradientn for use of a specific color map and color breaks.
I find that I cannot make it work without using limits = , however, that curtails any values that are beyond the limits.
Edit: It is important to note that the color-value combinations are fixed, to be consistent with other visualizations. Rescaling of the colors from e.g. -3 to 3 therefore is not an option.
Here is a minimal example:
library(tidyverse)
# Inputs
colorscale <- c("#760005", "#ec0013", "#ffa938", "#fdd28a", "#fefe53", "#ffffff", "#a2fd6e", "#00b44a", "#008180", "#2a23eb", "#a21fec")

breaks <- c(-2.00, -1.50, -1.20, -0.70, -0.50, 0.00, 0.50, 0.70, 1.20, 1.50, 2.00)

df <- data.frame(
  year = seq(2000:2020),
  value = c(0.24, 1.74, -2.33, 1.48, 0.38, 0.64, 0.97, -1.83, -1.25, -0.49, 3.15, -0.16, -0.12, 0.09, -1.67, -0.64, 0.39, 0.52, -0.58, 0.74, -1.24)
)

# Plot the data
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = value)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "#c5c5c5c5", linewidth = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = colorscale,
                       values = scales::rescale(breaks),
                       na.value = "#e5e5e5")

This results in a colorscale not centered on 0:

I can force it using the limits argument, but that curtails the extreme values (that I am most interested in):
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = value)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "#c5c5c5c5", linewidth = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = colorscale,
                       values = scales::rescale(breaks),
                       limits = c(-2,2),
                       na.value = "#e5e5e5")


I am aware that the intervals between colors are not uniform in my color scale (due to physics reasons), however, they are symmetrical.
I understand that scale_*_gradientn may not be what I should use.
Thank you!

I just found the answer myself shortly after posting:
Using limits, and then adding the argument oob = scales::squish for out of bounds definition is what is needed. Simple as that.
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = value)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "#c5c5c5c5", linewidth = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = colorscale,
                       values = scales::rescale(breaks),
                       limits = c(-2,2),
                       oob = scales::squish,
                       na.value = "#e5e5e5")



You could calculate the limits with a zero center by the absolute max of your range of values. Then multiple the min by -1 and max with +1 to have an equal range scale to 0 like this:
library(tidyverse)

center_limits <- max(abs(df$value))*c(-1, 1)

# Plot the data
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = value)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "#c5c5c5c5", linewidth = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = colorscale,
                       values = scales::rescale(breaks),
                       na.value = "#e5e5e5",
                       limits = center_limits)


Created on 2024-04-03 with reprex v2.0.2

Thanks. Rescaling like this is not really an option for consistency with other visualizations. The colors are fixed to the break values. This means, anything above 2 should have this deep purple, and below 2 this deep red.
